# got "undefined" when fetching from api other than https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json

Tags: react-native

I follow this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html#using-fetch to learn how to fetch data from a remote api and it is working great. However, whenever I change the url https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json of that example to another public api, I got "undefined" in my debugger and no data to display. Even the NASA API is returning that.
Any Idea?

```
const apiHost1 = 'https://facebook.github.io';
const apiHost2 = 'http://countryapi.gear.host';
const apiHost3 = 'https://api.nasa.gov';
export default {
  async fectchInitialOrders(){
    try {
    let response = await fetch(apiHost1 + '/react-native/movies.json');
    let responseJson = await response.json();
    return responseJson.movies;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  },

  async fectchInitialCountry(){
    try {
    let response = await fetch(apiHost2 + '/v1/Country/getCountries/');
    let responseJson = await response.json();
    return responseJson.movies;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  },

  async fectchNasaData(){
    try {
    let response = await fetch(apiHost3 + '/planetary/apod?api_key=NNKOjkoul8n1CH18TWA9gwngW1s1SmjESPjNoUFo');
    let responseJson = await response.json();
    return responseJson.movies;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

};
```

Only the facebook one is returning data

Comment: Please post your fetch api call with public url code. I understand you provided a link but want to see your code as you might be doing something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm hitting the NASA API from the url that you have used and there is no key called 'movies' in the response. You are trying to access the movies key from the NASA API response which doesn't exist which is why you are probably getting the error.

Comment: You are 100% right. I copy the Facebook example and forgot to change the object name. Thank you very much.